# Arithmetic Questions:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There was one Mess for 30 boarders in a certain hotel. If the number of boarders was increased by 10, the expenses of the mess increased by rs40 per month, while the average expenditure per head diminished by rs 2 . Find the original monthly expenses

**I am not able to solve this question, How to solve ? please anyone guide me for the Answer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

If the mess spends $x $ amount on thirty boarders, the average expenditure for the thirty boarders is $=\displaystyle \frac {x}{30} $.

Similarly, the average expenditure for forty boarders is $=\displaystyle \frac {x+40}{40} $.

Thus , $$\frac {x}{30} - \frac {x+40}{40} =2$$

Hope you can take it from here.